# FullCalendar stops loading when special characters are found

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

When I add a title like e.g my's Birthday calendar stop loading

Here My script:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay,listMonth'
    },
    weekNumbers: true,
    editable: true,
    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,
    //Select function
    //Event render
    //Event drop
    //Event resize
    events: [
    <?php foreach($events as $event): 
       //Fetch data dynamically
       title: '<?php echo $event['title']; ?>',
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    ]
});
```

How can I do?

Comment: Have you looked at the Javascript console in the browser? Any error messages?

Comment: it show Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes because the single quot seems to end your string. You should try to escape the special character. You can try this:

```
title : 'my\'s Birthday'
```

**OR**

```
title : "my's Birthday"
```

**OR**

```
title : 'my&quot;s Birthday'
```

Comment: can you update your answer showing your code when you add **title**?

Comment: ok it's working.  i change apostrophe to quotation mark        e.g, title : "<?php echo $event['title']; ?>",